# Slow performance on scroll with flutter charts

Tags: flutter

I have a `DraggableScrollableSheet` with a `ListView`, and inside that some flutter charts. When the draggable scrollable sheet go from `minChildSize` to `maxChildSize` the charts are constantly rebuilt, so it's laggy and with poor performance.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/xYoXYj4M7cM), you can see what I mean. This is from the android emulator but is the same on my Huawei P30 Pro

This is the code:

```dart
class SummaryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      // alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 120.0,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            CountrySelector(),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            ConfirmedCases(),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            DiseaseSummary(),
          ],
        ),
        DraggableScrollableSheet(
          maxChildSize: 1.0,
          initialChildSize: 0.4,
          minChildSize: 0.4,
          expand: true,
          builder: (ctx, scrollController) =>
              NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
            onNotification: (overscroll) {
              overscroll.disallowGlow();
              return null;
            },
            child: ListView(
              controller: scrollController,
              children: [
                SummaryCharts(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class SummaryCharts extends StatelessWidget {
  const SummaryCharts({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: double.infinity, height: 200, color: Colors.red),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ProgressChart(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              ProgressChart(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              ProgressChart(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


class ProgressChart extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PhysicalShape(
      elevation: 5,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 18.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'DATA HISTORY',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 16.0,
                          height: 16.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Confirmed',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 9.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 12.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 16.0,
                          height: 16.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFF69FF98),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Recovered',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 9.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 250,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
              child: BlocBuilder<CovidStatisticsBloc, CovidStatisticsState>(
                builder: (ctx, state) => charts.TimeSeriesChart(
                  _createSeries(
                    ctx,
                    state.stats.historicalConfirmed,
                    state.stats.historicalRecovered,
                  ),
                  animate: false,
                  customSeriesRenderers: [
                    charts.LineRendererConfig(
                      customRendererId: 'cases_series',
                      includeArea: true,
                      includePoints: true,
                      radiusPx: 4.0,
                      areaOpacity: 0.4,
                    ),
                    charts.LineRendererConfig(
                      customRendererId: 'recovered_series',
                      includeArea: true,
                      includePoints: true,
                      radiusPx: 4.0,
                      areaOpacity: 0.4,
                    )
                  ],
                  domainAxis: charts.DateTimeAxisSpec(
                    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                      labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        fontFamily: 'Mali',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        lineHeight: 2,
                        color: charts.Color(
                          a: 0xFF,
                          r: 0x68,
                          g: 0x81,
                          b: 0x8F,
                        ),
                      ),
                      lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                        thickness: 5,
                        color: charts.Color(
                          a: 0xFF,
                          r: 0xCD,
                          g: 0xD5,
                          b: 0xDA,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                    tickFormatterSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec(
                        (value) => NumberFormat.compact().format(value)),
                    renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                      labelStyle: charts.TextStyleSpec(
                        fontFamily: 'Mali',
                        fontSize: 12,
                        lineHeight: 2,
                        color: charts.Color(
                          a: 0xFF,
                          r: 0x68,
                          g: 0x81,
                          b: 0x8F,
                        ),
                      ),
                      lineStyle: charts.LineStyleSpec(
                        thickness: 5,
                        color: charts.Color(
                          a: 0xFF,
                          r: 0xCD,
                          g: 0xD5,
                          b: 0xDA,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the widget is being rebuilt each time you scroll, try changing the page to extend `StatefulWidget`, and in the state of the widget create a variable to store your `DraggableScrollableSheet` and initialize it in the `initState` function.

Answer (score -1):

it will be fixed in release mode you can cheek it `"flutter build apk"`

Comment: This must be a comment rather as a separate answer.

Comment: It's the same on release